# Headphone Jack Not Recognized and No Option Popup on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: grub2, 22.04, headphones, audio-jack

I'm encountering an issue with my Ubuntu installed my new system where the headphone jack is not recognized. Normally, when I plug in my headphones, I expect to see a popup window that allows me to choose between headset, headphone, and microphone options. Unfortunately, this is not happening.

I also had trouble with installing Ubuntu on my ExpertBook B7 flip and couldn't install grub so I used boot-repair to solve the problem.

This issue is new to me, If you need any information, let me know please.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That kind of popup window never existed on Linux. If you want to do what that does, you can use `hdajackretask`

Comment: @DanielT I always had it in all other distros

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it is supposed to look like?